# pcap.h file in Xilinx Vivado HLS

Tags: xilinx, libpcap, vivado, vivado-hls

I have used the pcap.h header file to parse a pcap file in Linux. The program compiles and parses the packets correctly. However, I want to put the same logic on a FPGA, for which I am using the Xilinx Vivado HLS tool. I am facing issues with the linking of pcap.h file in Xilinx Vivado. So, now I have two options:
1. How to link an external library in Xilinx Vivado HLS ?
2. If 1. is not possible, I would want to know if it is possible to parse a pcap packet without using the pcap.h header file?

Comment: An addition to your request is what you want to do. If you want pcap for network monitoring possibly you get different problems. For example on the Zynq architecture it is possible that your ethernet is only connected to the ARM processors so you could use Linux to do that.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to link an external library into the Vivado HLS synthesis processes. It requires all the C/C++ source files when generating RTL. However, it is possible to link with external libraries when testing using C simulation or RTL/C co-simulation. In both cases you need to edit the *CFLAGS* and *Linker Flags* settings under *Project Settings - Simulation*.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 things.

1. All code which should be converted to HW has to have a source.
2. libpcap can not be obviously used to read packet from FPGA interfaces.
3. For simulation purposes (I expect this is what you want) the rules are same as for generic c/c++ program. You need to add include directory where the pcap.h is stored in order to include it and you have to link the libpcap library in order to link final test executable. You can find this settings in project properties. Or you can write your make for the tests.